# Scrolling with a touch screen

Tags: 13.10, multi-touch, touchscreen

On a touchscreen, dragging your finger around behaves like you are using a mouse.  Is there any way to make dragging on a touch screen scroll rather than select the text?
I'm running ubuntu desktop 13.10 with kernel 3.11.6-amd64

Comment: Please edit your question with what OS are you using and its version.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 with kernel 3.11.6-amd64

Comment: Its a Firefox problem. But do update if you have found something that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu Unity currently only supports 3/4 finger touch gestures https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch... However, it is suggested you can use Ginn https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Ginn to define custom gestures. I have not tested it (yet) but bou might be able to make it work for you.